# highcharts large heat map drilldwon

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

i'm looking for an example of a drilldown on large heatmap of highcharts for a csv data?
first, a large heatmap is created using csv data. I should be able to select a part of the heatmap and drilldown further to see the details.

Comment: I don't think that drilldown is supported with canvas module. I cannot think of use case for that - you drilldown by clicking a specific point, when in the canvas example you have thousands of point. What you may be looking for is rendering grouped data at first, and after selecting the area, fetching and showing more detailed data. With less number of points use a regular heatmap without canvas mod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It behaves the same way other drill down chart works, Probably you can go through this sample

You have to set a drilldown series by parsing the csv data

```
  drilldown: function (e) {
             if (!e.seriesOptions) {
  }
```

**[HEATMAP DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/nr5em7wL/)**

Comment: what i was looking for is a drilldown on this chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas